# Missing or insufficient permissions even with a public database

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-firestore, gatsby

I had a Gatsby/firebase project working fine and stayed one week without changing anything. Now I just came back to update some stuff and I'm having the following error:

```
index.js:2177 FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (http://localhost:8000/commons.js:4331:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (http://localhost:8000/commons.js:19005:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (http://localhost:8000/commons.js:19502:44)
    at PersistentListenStream../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage (http://localhost:8000/commons.js:15457:43)
    at http://localhost:8000/commons.js:15386:30
    at http://localhost:8000/commons.js:15426:28
    at http://localhost:8000/commons.js:5669:20
```

I thought that I may have some bug on my firebase rules then I changed it to public:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm still getting the same error. I tried:

-updating npm dependencies

-clear the application storage

-gatsby clean

and none of these works. The firebase authentication is working fine. Any guesses where the problem may be?

EDIT:
I'm using sagas to read the code:

firebase.js

```
...
export const authRef = function() {
  return firebase.auth();
}

export const firestoreRef = function() {
  return firebase.firestore();
}
...
```

```
import {firestoreRef, authRef} from './firebase';

function* loadProjectsData() {
  try {

    const firestore = firestoreRef();

    const userId = authRef().currentUser.uid;
    const query =
      firestoreRef()
        .collection('projects')

    const snap = yield call(
      [
        query,
        query.get
      ]
    );
  } catch(error)  {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that actually reads/writes to your question. Without that it's hard to say anything about why your rules are failing.

Comment: Sure @FrankvanPuffelen. I just added :)

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't immediately see what wrong. Can you give it a try with `allow read, write: if true;`? I never depend on an empty condition myself, and wonder if that has changed. If that's not it, I hope somebody else sees what's wrong.

Comment: I just changed the rule as you said and it didn't work :(. I started to think that it may be a bug from firebase server. I requested their support to see if it's a problem in my code or a bug in their servers. It doesn't work in other computers or in the anonymous tab as well

Comment: It could be a bug of course, but I'd expect more folks to be reporting it. Any way: the support team is a great way to help with that (as they can have a look at your project if needed), so let's see what else we can do here. Can you try to reproduce the problem in the simulator in the Firebase console?

Comment: I can't reproduce in the simulator. Everything works fine there. I can access any data logged or not logged. I can't query on other browsers or computer as well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem. A member from my team ended up making a change in the IAM configurations from google cloud that disabled the service account that applies firebase rules in the firestore.

With the help from Firebase Support team I was able to discover it. So I just checked the history of changes and undid the one that broke the access to the database